# place custom control buttons on agm

Tags: angular, custom-controls

I need to place some custom control buttons on top of agm-map and i need to handle the click event for those placed buttons. I am unable to place custom buttons.

template.html as below

```
    <agm-map [latitude]="lat" #map [longitude]="lng" [zoom]=7>
      <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
    </agm-map>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: stackblitz would make it easier to help

Comment: isn't your `agm-marker` supposed to behave like a button itself? maybe you just need a `click` event on it.

Comment: @PushkarAdhikari I don't think that is what he means, Having a custom button much like the zoom in/out UI buttons would be very useful.

Comment: Exactly @PushkarAdhikari, i tried a lot, i couldn't  get it done. then changed the UI design little.